# What is fork() doing here?

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, pid

So I am trying to figure out what this code is doing:

```
int k = 5;
 if(fork() == fork()) ++k; else --k;
 printf("%d\n", k);
```

The thing that bothers me is that I receive different outputs:

```
4
4
4
6
```

```
4
4
4
```

```
4
4
6
4
```

```
4
4
6
```

```
4
6
4
4
```

I have added a PID detector so I see the ids of all the processes:

```
int main ()
{
   int k = 5;
    if(fork() == fork()) ++k; else --k;
    printf("%d\n", k);
    int pid;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
         printf("\n Process id : %d",getpid());
         printf("\n Parrent process id : %d\n" ,getppid());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But sometimes I get the output:

```
Process id : 9472
 Parrent process id : 1413

 Process id : 9474
 Parrent process id : 1413

 Process id : 9471
 Parrent process id : 1413

 Process id : 9473
 Parrent process id : 1413
```

or:

```
 Process id : 9557
 Parrent process id : 1413

 Process id : 9556
 Parrent process id : 1413

 Process id : 9558
 Parrent process id : 9554

 Process id : 9559
 Parrent process id : 9553
```

**Please make me understand what is happening here.**

Comment: Re “The thing that bothers me is that I receive different outputs:”: The operating system does not guarantee the order in which the processes will execute. Consequently, the outputs from the various child and parent processes appear in different orders. And, since your program does not wait for child processes to finish, sometimes a parent exits before its child prints, and then the child is reattached to another process that takes the place of the original parent.

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to see what's happening if you [do like this](https://godbolt.org/z/jT3TPnWqz)

Comment: Something is fishy there, @EricPostpischil. If a process `A`'s parent terminates before `A` itself does, then `A` should be inherited by process 1, no other.

Comment: Your "PID detector" `fork()`s *again*, and then reports the PIDs of (only) the child processes from those additional forks.  None of the processes that report PPIDs that way are among the ones that earlier printed a value of `k` -- they are children of those processes.  That seems an odd thing to do, and I'm not sure what you think it's telling you.

Comment: Well, I used the "PID detector" in the hope of not modifying the code above, I have to come up with something to detect the PIDs independently then, any ideas?

Comment: @Jorj2014 What about [this](https://godbolt.org/z/7sh51f86s) or [this](https://godbolt.org/z/a7fbhjv6z)?

Comment: @Jorj2014, it's still not clear to me what you intended to gain or think you are gaining via that additional `fork()`.  I don't see any particular way in which it helps you avoid changing the preceding code.  What would you lose if you just didn't `fork` again?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you very much I think I understand it a little bit better now!

Comment: In any case, the complete program presented does not fully reproduce the output presented for me.  It always prints three "4"s and one "6", in various orders (which is to be expected), never just three digits.  It also always prints "Parrent process id : 1" four times, which is a plausible result for the given code, but not the only allowed one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the first part of the code that I posted in the question is important, and I have to use it, the PID detector was found online and I didn't know it's so effective, if you have another way of detecting the PIDs, I am more than happy to use yours and repalce that extra fork().

Comment: Again, @Jorj2014, what if you just didn't `fork` that extra time? That detector uses `getpid()` to get the current process's PID (and `getppid()` to get its parent's PID).  The `fork()` usage changes which PIDs will be reported by those calls -- which is unhelpful for your particular case -- and is in no way a prerequisite for those calls.  Frankly, I'm not sure where you found that, but it seems to have been designed with some special purpose in mind.

Comment: Well, @JohnBollinger looks like it works if I only print the getpid and getppid without the extra fork(), but why 1 of the 4 processes have a different parent sometimes, or 2 out of the 4? Is it what Eric Postpischil said above?

Comment: @Jorj2014, something very strange is happening in your environment.  It seems to be failing to conform to POSIX.  You should always see one of the following cases (i) at least one of the processes reports its parent process ID as 1, or (ii) as a group, the processes report exactly three distinct parent process IDs.  In the latter case, you should furthermore see that the duplicate PPID and one of the other two are also reported as PIDs of others of the processes.  Just where and how are you running this, anyway?

Comment: I am running this in Ubuntu Virtual Box using Visual Studio Code using gcc in the terminal.

Comment: @Jorj2014, I suggest testing the program by running it directly from a command line, not inside Visual Studio Code.  Pretty much all IDEs are susceptible to producing unusual effects in programs that are run through their internal program-running facilities, VSC no less than most.  You will very likely still see some variation in your output when you run from the command line, but you are much less likely to see any three-`k` results, and you should consistently see PPID 1 reported by processes whose original parents have terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expanded your original code to `wait` for the children so that you'll be sure to get all output and added some more output.

You have two `fork`s so there will be four processes in total.

Only in one of these processes will `fork() == fork()` be `true`. It's when the first called of those two `fork()`s returns to a child process and the next `fork()` is called and also returns to a child process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char *foo(pid_t a, pid_t b) {
    if (a == b) return "child,child";
    if (a && b) return "parent,parent";
    if (a) return "parent,child";
    return "child,parent";
}

int main() {
    int k = 5;
    pid_t p1, p2;

    if ((p1 = fork()) == (p2 = fork())) {
        ++k;
    } else {
        --k;
    }

    printf("%d %s\tppid=%d  pid=%d\n", k, foo(p1, p2), getppid(), getpid());

    int wstatus;
    if (p1) wait(&wstatus);
    if (p2) wait(&wstatus);
}
```

Example output. Note that the order may change since all the processes run at the same time.

```
6 child,child   ppid=2  pid=4
4 parent,child  ppid=1  pid=3
4 child,parent  ppid=1  pid=2
4 parent,parent ppid=0  pid=1
```

Here the first process, `1`, creates `2` and `3` and it is in the case where `2` was created that we got `fork() == fork()`.

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
 /
4
```

Comment: Thank you very much @TedLyngmo, but I am not really sure I understand who ppid=0 is, the initial process is 1 isn't it? So who is 0?

Comment: @Jorj2014 You're welcome! I ran the code in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/eEdvbzr4d) and in that container, `0` is the "system" process and `1` is the first process of the program you run.

Answer (score 0):

> The thing that bothers me is that I receive different outputs:

The code presented unconditionally `fork()`s twice.  After the first `fork` succeeds, there are two processes where originally there was one.  *Both* execute the second `fork`, so, provided that all the `fork` calls succeed, there are eventually four processes.

On success, `fork()` returns the child PID to the original process and 0 to the child.  On failure, it returns -1 to the parent (and there is no child).  If in fact both `fork`s succeed then all the resulting processes' PIDs will differ, so the only case in which `fork() == fork()` will evaluate to true is in the child of the first child, in which both `fork()` calls will have returned 0.  In that process alone, `k` will be incremented; in the other processes it will be decremented.

The processes do not share memory, so the increments and decrements are reflected separately in the various processes' separate copies of `k`.  No control having been exerted over the order in which the various processes run, they may, in principle, print their values of `k` in any order.  That covers three of the observed outputs.

But what about the cases where only three values of `k` are printed?  The most likely explanation for these is that the first `fork()` succeeds, but in one of the resulting processes the second one fails, returning -1.  If it is in the original process that the `fork()` failure occurs then the successful instance of the second `fork()` will still produce one process in which `fork() == fork()` evaluates to true.  On the other hand, if it is in the first child that the `fork` failure occurs then there will be no process in `fork() == fork()` evaluates to true.  This would explain the two three-output results.

---

As far as the PIDs and PPIDs go, one thing that seems to be throwing you is the effect of some of the processes' parent processes terminating.  A process other than the initial one *always* has a living process as its parent.  If the original parent of process `P` terminates before `P` itself does, then a different parent is assigned; **on a POSIX-conforming system, that will be process 1**.

Because your program does nothing to ensure that the parent processes outlive their children, you are sometimes seeing the effects of some of the original parents terminating before their children.  This explains the variations in the patterns of PPIDs.  However, you seem to be running your program in an environment (presumably some kind of container) that does not conform to POSIX with regard to details of the assignment of the new parent, which is somewhat disguising the source of that issue.